# Disable or remove seconds from World Clock widget

Tags: macos, ventura, clock, dashboard-widget, widgets

Here you can see two widgets World Clock (with four small faces) and the normal Clock (in macOS Ventura 13.1):

[image: Mac OS widgets: World Clock and regular Clock]

The orange hand for seconds is appearing and smoothly moving in all the clock faces.

I don't mind having it in the regular Clock, but I think it's redundant to also have it in the World Clock.

**Is there any way to remove or hide the seconds hand from the World Clock widget?**

I am considering installing one of the third party widgets from Mac App Store, such as "Hour - World Clock" or "World Clock Widgets". But I wanted to check if it's possible on the standard widget provided by Apple.